# How do you hide .git project directories?

Tags: regex, git, nginx

Now that I have nginx setup I need to be able to hide my `.git` directories. What kind of rewrite would I need to stop prying eyes? And where in the `server {}` or `http {}` block would it go?

Comment: The answer is in the answers, but if you want to make sure you did it right (or read more about the vulnerability), check out [GitTools](https://github.com/internetwache/GitTools).

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
http {
  server {
    location ~ /\.git {
      deny all;
    }
  }
}
```

This `location` directive will deny access to any `.git` directory in any subdirectory.

**Note:** This location block must be before your main location block, so that it can be evaluated first.

Comment: Does this work if the `.git` folder is in a subdirectory like `/folder/.git/`?

Comment: Yes, it does. "location ~" matches *regular expression*, not a sub-path.

Comment: have in mind that this location block has to be the **first** location block. otherwise other blocks might precede it. in most scenarios just one location block is processed.

Comment: If you have multiple, virtual servers, can you add this configuration blob once before all other servers, or must it be replicated in each server?

Answer (score 58):

Hidden directories and files should never be web accessible. The general answer to your question is:

```
  location ~ /\.  { return 403; }
```

This denies access to .git, .svn, .htaccess and similar files in any subdirectory.

Comment: Not exactly what the question asked for - but he's right anyway :)

Comment: I would go further and say that no one should know they exist, period! (Not just that they should always be denied access to them). Thus, your answer changes from `return 403;` to `return 404;` ... This way, the individual attempting to access it will not know if it truly exists.

Comment: deny all is preferred over return 403: https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs/issues/126

Comment: Agree "protect all hidden directories" is a sane default, but consider `.well-known` / [RFC5785](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5785) is one hidden directory / aliased resource which should be accessible in a dot-location.

Comment: `location ~ /\..* { return 404; }` all files in directories (including subdirectories) starting with a dot.

Answer (score 12):

With other solutions I could download `/.git/config` and others, just `/.git` was protected. This one denies everything starting with a dot, regardless how deep the requested URL is:

```
location ~ /\.(.*)/?(.*)? {
    return 404;
}
```

Comment: `location ~ /\..* { return 404; }` all files in directories (including subdirectories) starting with a dot.

Answer (score 1):

This will prevent someone from hitting the http://example.com/.git but if your working in a subdirectory like this http://example.com/example/.git it will fail. You really need:

```
location ~ .*/\.git {
    deny all;
}
```

Comment: I just tested this and `location ~ /\.          { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }` will block access to hidden subdirectories. So I don't think the extra `.*` is necessary.